# Get events from server to client in jsp

Tags: java, dom-events, portlet

We are developing jsr-286 portlet based application with JSP and Javascript as the client-side technology. When we receive a JMS message in the controller how will client get notified without page refresh. We have a constraint not to poll as it causes performance overhead. We have tried server sent events and websocket, which works fine in servlets and not in portlets.

Is there any way we can achieve this in portlet?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax services. Using Ajax you can dynamically update the page based on the server response.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to achieve this.